# How to sync ICAL file with google calendar using php or jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have to sync the ical file with the google calendar and iCalender onclick using php or jquery i have created the ical file but i don't know how to sync. please help, thank you.

The code which i user to generate the ical file given below so i need to pass this ical file to sync the file with the google calender

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","calendarevent");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  // Create connection

// Check connection
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id,title,dates FROM events";
$result = $con->query($sql);

/*if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}*/


$ics_contents  = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n";
$ics_contents .= "VERSION:2.0\n";
$ics_contents .= "PRODID:PHP\n";
$ics_contents .= "METHOD:PUBLISH\n";
$ics_contents .= "X-WR-CALNAME:Schedule\n";

# Change the timezone as well daylight settings if need be
$ics_contents .= "X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/New_York\n";
$ics_contents .= "BEGIN:VTIMEZONE\n";
$ics_contents .= "TZID:America/New_York\n";
$ics_contents .= "BEGIN:DAYLIGHT\n";
$ics_contents .= "TZOFFSETFROM:-0500\n";
$ics_contents .= "TZOFFSETTO:-0400\n";
$ics_contents .= "DTSTART:20070311T020000\n";
$ics_contents .= "RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU\n";
$ics_contents .= "TZNAME:EDT\n";
$ics_contents .= "END:DAYLIGHT\n";
$ics_contents .= "BEGIN:STANDARD\n";
$ics_contents .= "TZOFFSETFROM:-0400\n";
$ics_contents .= "TZOFFSETTO:-0500\n";
$ics_contents .= "DTSTART:20071104T020000\n";
$ics_contents .= "RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU\n";
$ics_contents .= "TZNAME:EST\n";
$ics_contents .= "END:STANDARD\n";
$ics_contents .= "END:VTIMEZONE\n";

while ($schedule_details = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $id            = $schedule_details['id'];
  $title         = $schedule_details['title'];
  $dates         = $schedule_details['dates'];


  $estart_date   = str_replace("-", "", $dates);
 $eend_date   = str_replace("-", "", $dates);



  # Replace some HTML tags
  $title          = str_replace("<br>", "\\n",   $title);
  $title          = str_replace("&amp;", "&",    $title);
  $title          = str_replace("&rarr;", "-->", $title);
  $title          = str_replace("&larr;", "<--", $title);
  $title          = str_replace(",", "\\,",      $title);
  $title          = str_replace(";", "\\;",      $title);


  # Change TZID if need be
  $ics_contents .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\n";
  $ics_contents .= "DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York"     . $estart_date . "\n";
  $ics_contents .= "DTEND:"       . $eend_date . "\n";
  $ics_contents .= "DTSTAMP:"     . date('Ymd') . "T". date('His') . "Z\n";
  $ics_contents .= "SUMMARY:"     . $title . "\n";
  $ics_contents .= "UID:"         . $id . "\n";
  $ics_contents .= "SEQUENCE:0\n";
  $ics_contents .= "END:VEVENT\n";
}

$ics_contents .= "END:VCALENDAR\n";
/* print_r($ics_contents);exit();*/
# File to write the contents

$ics_file   = 'schedule.ics';

if (is_writable($ics_file)) {
  if (!$handle = fopen($ics_file, 'w')) {
     echo "Cannot open file ($ics_file)\n\n";
     exit;
  }

  # Write $ics_contents to opened file
  if (fwrite($handle, $ics_contents) === FALSE) {
    echo "Cannot write to file ($ics_file)\n\n";
    exit;
  }

  # echo "Success, wrote to <b>schedule.ics</b><br>\n\n";

  fclose($handle);

} else {
  echo "The file <b>$ics_file</b> is not writables\n\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: @JeuneGuerrier I have added the code which i have done so far, thank you

Comment: **Never** get your application to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes. Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.

Comment: Anyway it's not clear what you want to do with this ics file? What do you mean by sync it with google calendar, exactly? AFAIK google's API does not accept ics files as input, unless you can point me to documentation which describes this?

Answer (score 0):

The 'syncing' is determined by the user who owns the google calendar or the icalendar.  It is a one-way sync, updates go from your feed to the destination applications.

You provide the url for the ics file/feed.  The users subscribe to the feed using the url.  Google and icalendar will check the feed for updates.